# Set Height to Div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a repeater inside of a div and I would like to set the height of the inner div(com) to 200px. Although, it my jquery doesn't seem to work. Can someone shed a little light? Thanks.

```
<div  id="comments" style="width:480px;  float:left;">
    <div id="com">
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptComments" runat="server" >
          <ItemTemplate>
              <%# Eval("COMMENTS") %>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#comments com").css(function () {
        ("#comments com").height("200px");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#com").css("height","200px");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/xy7hcvna/)**

Answer (score 0):

No need for a callback:

```
    $("#comments #com").css('height','200px');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.css` is not an event trigger, also you are missing a `$` and a `#` in your code.

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $("#comments #com").height("200px"); 
    //you were missing $ to begin line and # to identify com
});
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vngLomdu/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

you can also user the jquery css attribute.

than you get something like this:

```
$('#divName').css('height','200px');
```